# MySQL SUM by field an then GROUP BY user?

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

[image: Following this table]

What's the correct query to get this result:

```
ID | Type | Total
1  |   A  | 300
1  |   B  | 100
2  |   A  | 30
2  |   B  | 40
```

Which means sum by `type` first and then group by `user id`?

Comment: `select user_id, type, sum(total) from payouts group by user_id, type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your aggregate functions, such as SUM, are performed on your groups; so there is no "SUM by type first then group by user_id", you are wanting to group by user_id and type.

Like so: `GROUP BY user_id, type`

If you want to guarantee that ordering in the future also have an `ORDER BY user_id, type` clause as well. *Currently, `GROUP BY` also orders, but I believe that feature has been marked as deprecated recently.*

Comment: Yup, but when I try this approach the numbers don't add up...it just takes on record from 'type' column

Comment: @Broshi `group by user_id, type` should be sufficient. You're sure you put BOTH in the group by? If that is not working, you should post the query you tried and what results it actually gave you.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM payouts
GROUP BY user_id, payout_type
ORDER BY user_id, payout_type

Comment: You need to actually select the sum, not just the fields.